# Why I am getting two different plots for same data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, xticks

I have a [data file](http://www.filedropper.com/data_21).  (duration : One day)

I want to plot time vs temp graph.
I tried to plot it using two different block of codes. The methods are standard but I am getting two different plots.

In first method I used time in `datetime` datatype

```
#method
t=pd.to_datetime(data['time'],format='%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.time
data['time']=t
data.drop('index',axis=1,inplace=True)
ax=data.plot(x='time',color=['tab:blue','tab:red'])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
```

[image]

In second method I used time in string format

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data['time'], data['temp'])
ax.plot(data['time'], data['temp_mean'],color='red')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
y1,y2=float(data.temp.min()),float(data.temp.max())
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(y1,y2),10)
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Temp')
plt.show()
```

The second plot is the expected one. But the one I got have overlapped x ticks. I need to have xticks in hourly format (1 hr frequency)

[image]

Why I am getting plots with two different pattern? How to add xticks with 1 hour frequency?

Comment: *time in string format* -> that's your problem. by using string, you ignore the underlying time information.

Comment: My guess is when x-axis is strings, all the values are jammed together and not properly distributed along the axis.

Comment: `ax=data.plot(x='time', color=['tab:blue','tab:red'], rot=45)` not `ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)`

Comment: What happens if you add `data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'],format='%H:%M:%S.%f')` at the beginning of the second method?

Comment: `data['time']=t` is weird formatting, do as in the previous comment.

Comment: `datetime` and `string` are NOT the same data. So you use different data and you get different plots.